# I want to remove part of a header

Tags: themes, headers

Here's my question: I want to remove the second part of the header (a certain bar) of this page: http://marbleconsulting.nl/?page_id=127 . I want to remove the part that says 'home > testimonials'. I want to remove that bar. How do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You should search in your template files for a file named header.php and look for the `<div id="breadcrumb"></div>` and you could just remove the code.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a css like below

```
#breadcrumbs{
display:none !important;
}
```

Method 2 :
edit the header.php file (have a check on page.php if it is not there) and remove the div

Comment: The element will still be in the HTML if we inspect the code. I prefer completly removing if from the DOM if you do not want to use it.

Comment: yeah it's a quick method that's it ..other wise the child theme needs to modified..i have updated the answer